# Rails Migration Error w/ Postgres when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

I'm trying to perform the following up migration to change the column "number" in the "tweet" model's table

```
class ChangeDataTypeForTweetsNumber < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :tweets do |t|
      t.change :number, :integer
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :tweets do |t|
      t.change :number, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Upon performing the the following up migration to heroku....

```
heroku rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120925211232
```

I get the following error

```
    PG::Error: ERROR:  column "number" cannot be cast to type integer
: ALTER TABLE "tweets" ALTER COLUMN "number" TYPE integer
```

Any thoughts you have would be very much appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html):

> [ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...]
>   The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

There is no implicit conversion from `varchar` to `int` in PostgreSQL so it complains that `column "number" cannot be cast to type integer` and the ALTER TABLE fails. You need to tell PostgreSQL how to convert the old strings to numbers to match the new column type and that means that you need to get a USING clause into your ALTER TABLE. I don't know of any way to make Rails do that for you but you can do it by hand easily enough:

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table tweets
    alter column number
    type integer using cast(number as integer)
  })
end
```

You'll want to watch out for values that can't be cast to integers, PostgreSQL will let you know if there are problems and you'll have to fix them before the migration will succeed.

Your existing down-migration should be fine, converting `integer` to `varchar` should be handled automatically.

Comment: For a more concise and idiomatic way to do it, check out riley's answer below!

Comment: @danmaz74: Do you know if that was available in 2012 or did I miss something?

Comment: @muistooshort I didn't want to criticize your answer, just highlight the other one (which came after yours) - many people don't read "other answers", but read comments to the top one

Comment: @danmaz74: No worries, I'm not throwing a hissy fit or anything like that, just curious if you knew if the "SQL snippet" argument to `change_column` is something new and official or just a trick that works because of the loose way that `change_column` is implemented. The Rails docs suggest that it is a trick but the Rails docs leave out all sorts of important things.

Comment: @muistooshort I honestly have no idea :)

Answer (score 47):

Same as above but a little bit more concise:

```
change_column :yourtable, :column_to_change, 'integer USING CAST("column_to_change" AS integer)'
```

Comment: Feels like AR should handle this really

Comment: Use this for a reversible migration in that case:
`reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        change_column :yourtable, :column_to_change, 'integer USING CAST("column_to_change" AS integer)'
      end
      dir.down do
        change_column :yourtable, :column_to_change, 'character varying USING CAST("column_to_change" AS character varying)'
      end
    end`