# Rake DB:Migration error when modifying the column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have written my migration file to change the column type as follows

```
class ChangeColumnTypeInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up




     execute <<-SQL
       ALTER TABLE batches
         ALTER COLUMN updated_by int
      SQL

     execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE batches
          ALTER COLUMN created_by int
     SQL

 end

def self.down
  end
end
```

but this gives me an error saying `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "int"
LINE 2:         ALTER COLUMN updated_by int`
 I could not find the error . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER COLUMN updated_by TYPE int USING (updated_by::integer)`

[Change type of varchar field to integer: "cannot be cast automatically to type integer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170570/change-type-of-varchar-field-to-integer-cannot-be-cast-automatically-to-type-i) could help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the word TYPE is needed here...

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-altertable.html

```
class ChangeColumnTypeInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    execute <<-SQL
     ALTER TABLE mt940_batches
     ALTER COLUMN updated_by TYPE int
    SQL

    execute <<-SQL
     ALTER TABLE mt940_batches
     ALTER COLUMN created_by TYPE int
    SQL
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Comment: um getting this error PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "updated_by" cannot be cast to type integer
:       ALTER TABLE mt940_batches
        ALTER COLUMN updated_by TYPE int

Comment: Did you try the solution provided by @GraemeMcLean? That actually does an explicit cast.

Comment: @Kalanamith, did you see the link in my answer?  There's talk on there specifically about your error - and some people have used trim in the cast.  Maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL so accordingly you need to use ActiveRecord in this case :

```
def self.up
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
connection.execute(put_your_sql_query_here)
end
```

Hope rest you can figure out easily.