# Postgresql operator class "varchar_pattern_ops" does not accept data type integer

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm trying migrate my data id postgresql from string to integers in django to use them in sphinx search. So first of all I'm making data migration, converting my data to integers in string like this

```
db.execute('''UPDATE the_table SET foo='1' WHERE foo='bar';''')
```

Then I'm making schema migration

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE integer USING (col_name::integer);
```

like it was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13170673/3049150)

But I'm getting an error

> ERROR: operator class "varchar_pattern_ops" does not accept data type integer
>
> SQL-состояние: 42804

This error occurs both in South and pgAdmin. The data is correct - it is Null or integer in string type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of postgres? It works fine in 9.3: `alter table test alter val type int using (val::int);`

Comment: 9.1.10. I don't understand - the other column is the same table just was converted to integer without errors. But this column is still causing error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm only able to reproduce your error message like so:

```
denis=# create index test_idx on test (val varchar_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX
denis=# alter table test alter val type int using (val::int);
ERROR:  operator class "varchar_pattern_ops" does not accept data type integer
```

If you've a funky index like that, try dropping and recreating it like so:

```
denis=# drop index test_idx;
DROP INDEX
denis=# create index test_idx on test (val);
CREATE INDEX
denis=# alter table test alter val type int using (val::int);
ALTER TABLE
```

Related docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html

Answer (score 14):

Dealing with this problem you have to use 2 steps of migrations.

**First:** Add `db_index=False` on your first migration then generate and run the migration.

**Second:** Update `db_index=True` to your related column in the model (according to the first step) then generate the migration and run again.

This is based on my experience on some projects, and it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, should be the accepted answer since it does not envolves SQL.

Comment: I tried this, but for my particular use case where a `ForeignKey` was a `character varying` in the PostgreSQL and not a `uuid` it didn't regen the correct migration files to update the column casting. I had to write pure SQL.  I don't feel that great about it though, and am surprised. I would think that the migrations should never get into that state.