# Migrate JSON column type to HSTORE column type

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I currently have the following db schema:

```
create_table :user_actions do |t|
  t.integer  :emitter_id
  t.string   :emitter_type
  t.integer  :target_id
  t.string   :target_type
  t.json     :payload
  t.timestamps
end
```

And I would like to migrate the `payload` field from `json` to `hstore`.

Doing the following:

```
change_column :user_actions, :payload, :hstore
```

Result in the following error message:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "payload" cannot be cast automatically to type hstore
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

**Not sure how to use the `USING` hint and what's the best way to do this migration without loosing any data ?**

Comment: Does [this example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html#AEN149208) help? (Section F.16.6. Compatibility)

Comment: this is probably doable @DrColossos example shows the postgres using clause.  I don't know much about ruby/activerecord, I did find this thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11062 which indicates that 1) you can't get to a using clause through activerecord and 2) the work around is going straight to sql.

Comment: Thx, actually went for a simple solution, rename column and do a simple migration `o.new_field = o.payload` where `new_field` is a `hstore`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**HINT:**  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion

**Actually the format is:**

```
change_column :user_actions, :payload, '[type_to_which_you_want_to_change] USING CAST(data AS [type_to_which_you_want_to_change])'
```

**So in your case:**

```
change_column :user_actions, :payload, 'hstore USING CAST(payload AS hstore)'
```

**Reference:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032193/1222852

Comment: This doesn't work.  Postgres can't cast JSON to HSTORE without using a custom function.  See my answer which does work.

Comment: Solved an issue I was facing.

Answer (score 3):

Taimoor Changaiz's answer is partially incorrect since postgresql cannot cast JSON to HSTORE without using a custom function.  Assuming your JSON is not nested, here's what will work:

```
  def self.up
    execute <<-SQL
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_json_to_hstore(json)
              RETURNS hstore
              IMMUTABLE
              STRICT
              LANGUAGE sql
            AS $func$
              SELECT hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
              FROM   json_each_text($1)
            $func$;
        SQL
    change_column :user_actions, :payload, 'hstore USING my_json_to_hstore(payload)'
    end

  def self.down
    change_column :user_actions, :payload, 'json USING CAST(payload AS json)'
    execute "DROP FUNCTION my_json_to_hstore(json)"
  end
```

Credit to pozs for his custom postgresql function here: [Casting JSON to HSTORE in Postgres 9.3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315948/casting-json-to-hstore-in-postgres-9-3)

Answer (score 2):

Went for a simple but working solution. Create a new column named `parameters` and do a simple migration script:

```
def up
  add_column :user_actions, :parameters, :hstore

  UserAction.find_each do |o|
    o.parameters = o.payload
    o.save!
  end

  remove_column :user_actions, :payload
end

def down
  add_column :user_actions, :payload, :json

  UserAction.find_each do |o|
    o.payload = o.parameters
    o.save!
  end

  remove_column :user_actions, :parameters
end
```