# Cast JSON to HSTORE in Postgres 9.3+?

Tags: json, postgresql, database-migration, hstore

I've read the docs and it appears that there's no discernible way to perform an `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... USING` statement to directly convert a `json` type column to an `hstore` type. There's no function available (that I'm aware of) to perform the cast.

The next best alternative I have is to create a new column of type `hstore`, copy my JSON data to that new column using some external tool, drop the old `json` column and rename the new `hstore` column to the old column's name.

Is there a better way?

What I have so far is:

```
$ CREATE TABLE blah (unstructured_data JSON);

$ ALTER TABLE blah ALTER COLUMN unstructured_data 
       TYPE hstore USING CAST(unstructured_data AS hstore);
```

> ```
> ERROR:   cannot cast type json to hstore
> ```

Comment: JSON can have multi dimensional arrays whereas hstore can not. This means that simply casting between the two isn't a straight forward procedure. There are plenty of user functions available so long as you are aware that the two data types are not always equal.

Comment: I hear you--assuming my JSON is not nested, has only quoted property names and has only strings for properties, should I be able to write a casting function from JSON to HSTORE? Or would you recommend perform this "update" operation in a for loop outside Postgres?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't allow all kind of expressions within the `USING` clause of `ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE ...` (f.ex. sub-queries are disallowed).

But, you can write a function to overcome this, you just need to decide what to do with advanced types (in object's values), like arrays & objects. Here is an example, which simply converts them to string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_json_to_hstore(json)
  RETURNS hstore
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $func$
  SELECT hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
  FROM   json_each_text($1)
$func$;
```

After that, you can use this in your `ALTER TABLE`, like:

```
ALTER TABLE blah
  ALTER COLUMN unstructured_data
  SET DATA TYPE hstore USING my_json_to_hstore(unstructured_data);
```

Comment: I get `Error : ERROR:  default for column "my_column" cannot be cast automatically to type hstore` when running the ALTER

Comment: In JSON, the last specification of a key wins, while it appears that in hstore, the first specification of a key wins. This means the results can be inconsistent with what you would expect coming from a JSON. One way to deal with that is run it through a sort of no-op PL/v8 function, which clears out the extraneous key specifications. That's probably unnecessary with `jsonb`.

Comment: @jpmc26 or, you can just add a `SELECT DISTINCT ON (key)` & `ORDER BY key` to my solution's function (`ASC|DESC` depending on what value you want to preserve -- or even a window-function can filter them out)

Comment: Just ordering by key wouldn't necessarily produce the same order as within the JSON, and the value doesn't give you the info to do that either. You *could* do something like `SELECT key, $1->>key FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key FROM json_object_keys($1) json_key (key)) distinct_key`, but this isn't really any better than a no-op PL/v8 function, imo.

Comment: @jpmc26: Excellent point. (Actually, the winner among duplicate keys is *undefined* for `hstore`.) I added an alternative version of pozs' smart function to cover the corner case.

Answer (score 1):

There is "trap" for **repeated keys** - allowed by both `json` and `hstore` input, but unfortunately resolved differently (!). Consider this example value:

```
json '{"double_key":"key1","foo":null,"double_key":"key2"}'
```

In `json`, 'double_key is effectively **'key2'**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)

> Because the `json` type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will
>   preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, as
>   well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object
>   within the value contains the same key more than once, all the
>   key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider **the last value** as the operative one.)

Bold emphasis mine.

In `hstore`, however, for the same order of key/value pairs, 'double_key' ***might*** effectively be **'key1'**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html)

> Each key in an `hstore` is unique. If you declare an `hstore` with
>   duplicate keys, only one will be stored in the `hstore` and there is **no guarantee as to which will be kept**:

Typically, the ***first*** instance of a key, but that's an implementation details that might change.

A simple and fast option to **always preserve the effective, operative value**: cast to `jsonb` before the conversion. [The manual again:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)

> [...] `jsonb` does not preserve white space, does not preserve
>   the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys.
>   If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.

Modifying [@pozs's conversion function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319295/939860):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json2hstore(json)
  RETURNS hstore AS
$func$
  SELECT hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
  FROM   jsonb_each_text($1::jsonb)  -- !
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Requires Postgres **9.4** or later. Postgres 9.3 has the `json` type, but not `jsonb`, yet. A no-op in PL/v8 might be alternative there, like [@jpmc mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315948/casting-json-to-hstore-in-postgres-9-3#comment53873014_28319295).