# postgresql changing column type from array to integer throwing casting error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am changing the postgresql column data type from integer[] to integer, while executing below query,

```
alter table contact_type alter column is_delete set data type integer USING is_delete::integer
```

i am getting below error

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer[] to integer
LINE 1: ...umn is_delete set data type integer USING is_delete::integer
                                                              ^
SQL state: 42846
Character: 86
```

but when tried to change datatype from varchar[] to char, below query works fine

```
alter table contact_type alter column ct_type set data type varchar
```

i have referred this link [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170570/change-type-of-varchar-field-to-integer-cannot-be-cast-automatically-to-type-i) but it is not working for converting array to normal data type..

Edit :- it is empty table without any data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick the array element that you want to use. You can't convert e.g. 42 integers to a single one.

E.g. if you want to use the first element of the array:

```
alter table contact_type  
    alter column is_delete 
    set data type integer USING is_delete[1];
```

---

But a column named `is_delete` should probably be a `boolean` rather than an integer.

Comment: i dont have any rows.. it is empty table with out any data

Comment: but above alter statement works, but it is not working for empty table without any rows

Comment: is_delete is integer of value 0 & 1, i dont want any charatects defining the boolean

Comment: a `boolean` is **not** "characters" - it's, well, a boolean. The statement will work just fine on an empty table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=704e4c45d9fd6d5ea3961b332c758835

Comment: but in the documentation, using "USING is_delete::integer" to cast integer[] to integer type, but it doesnt work, where as is_delete[1] doenst make sense, if the table is empty..

Comment: it takes the first element of a null array which in turn yields null which makes sense on an empty table