# Cannot change column type during migrating to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This what i am getting when i am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

`sender_id` was a `string`

```
==  ChangeTypeToInteger: migrating ============================================
-- change_column(:messages, :sender_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "sender_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "messages" ALTER COLUMN "sender_id" TYPE integer/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:652:in `exec'
```

Comment: This appears to be a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603498/rails-migration-error-w-postgres-when-pushing-to-heroku

Comment: my development db is sqlite , i think i will get errors if i used this in the migration file on sqlite3

Comment: I would highly recommend against using different databases in your different environments precisely for reasons like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote the manual [about `ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html):

> A USING clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment
>   cast from old to new type.

What you need is:

```
ALTER TABLE messages ALTER COLUMN sender_id TYPE integer
```

This **works with or without data** as long as all entries are convertible to `integer`.
If you have defined a `DEFAULT` for the column, you may have to drop and recreate that for the new type.

Here is [blog article on how to do this with ActiveRecord](http://webjazz.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-alter-columns-in-postgresql.html).