# How do I change a time column to an integer column in PostgreSQL with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, casting, rails-migrations

I have a column named `duration` in a table named `time_entries` in a PostgreSQL database connected to a new Rails app.  It is currently formatted to be time data, but I want it to be an integer.  (Specifically, I'm going for a smallint column because it will be an amount of minutes not exceeding one day i.e. 1440.)

First, I tried:

```
change_column :time_entries, :duration, :smallint, limit: 2
```

But I got the following error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "duration" cannot be cast automatically to type smallint
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING duration::smallint".
```

Then, after looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170570/change-type-of-varchar-field-to-integer-cannot-be-cast-automatically-to-type-i) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603498/rails-migration-error-w-postgres-when-pushing-to-heroku), I tried the following migration:

```
change_column :time_entries, :duration, 'integer USING CAST(duration AS integer)'
change_column :time_entries, :duration, :smallint, limit: 2
```

But the first line returned the following error:

```
PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type time without time zone to integer
```

How do I get it to convert? Time zone is irrelevant because it actually signifies a duration of time. I'm a Rails novice and know absolutely nothing about raw SQL code.

Comment: The other answers to this question are valid – they'll convert your Postgres TIME field into a Unix epoch, which is the number of seconds from the 1st of January 1970 – but that sounds like it's not what you really want here.

You're attempting to convert an _absolute_ time into a _delta_. To that end, you probably need some glue code in addition to your existing field to change that from an absolute reference in time to a duration. If that sounds right then let me know and I can write an answer to help you in that direction.

Comment: @JoshMcMillan - This statement of yours is not true: "they'll convert your Postgres TIME field into a Unix epoch, **which is the number of seconds from the 1st of January 1970**". Please try out the answers to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the information provided in the other answers, I did the following in a Rails migration:

```
change_column :time_entries, :duration, 'SMALLINT USING EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM duration)/60::SMALLINT'
```

This converted the column into SMALLINT numbers representing the amount of minutes.  I just wanted to include the final solution here since I modified the code from the other answers a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide an expression to do the actual conversion with a [`USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE time_entries
ALTER duration TYPE int2 USING EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM duration)::int2;
```

Be aware that any value exceeding the range of a `smallint` will raise an exception that aborts the whole transaction.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=76b4f1053fead75d6e4066b3c46fd234)*

Related:

- [Rails Migrations: tried to change the type of column from string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343383/rails-migrations-tried-to-change-the-type-of-column-from-string-to-integer/10343444#10343444)
- [Get a timestamp from concatenating day and time columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725418/get-a-timestamp-from-concatenating-day-and-time-columns/17732668#17732668)

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the epoch (number of seconds) from a TIME value pretty easily:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '01:00:00'::TIME)::INT
-- Returns 3600
```

In your case, I would suspect you could do this:

```
change_column :time_entries, :duration, 'integer USING EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM duration)::INT'
```